# Bootstrap Wizard launch in IE8 throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, internet-explorer-8

I am using Bootstrap wizard in my application to for my form and it works great in firefox but when I run it in IE (8) then I get the following javascript error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 245, column 9 in http://localhost:11014/common/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I tried rearranges my references to the javascript files and that didn't work and it seems like this error is pretty common but not sure what is wrong with the code since it works fine in firefox.

here is the specific lines mentioned:

```
return n || (n = x.Deferred(), "complete" === o.readyState ? setTimeout(x.ready) : (o.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", S, !1), e.addEventListener("load", S, !1))), n.promise(t)
```

Please advise me on how to correct this error.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? 2.0 or before?

Comment: @Johnny, I am using Jquery 2.0.3. and the error occured in the min.js file

Comment: Maybe you should try 1.9 instead. jQuery 2.0 doesn't support IE 8 or earlier.